# How do I know when I need to add something to my app.module.ts?

Tags: angular, dependencies

My `app.module.ts` needs to have added `FormsModule` to run my template code how do I know it?

The error was kind of cryptic,

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
```

What good is

```
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
```

In my Component if I don't have

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

in my my `app.module.ts` and that added to the `imports` array. Clearly, I know now that it's required, but how am I *supposed* to know that?

- Where is this easily documented?
- What errors should I look out for?

What exactly is the role of the `imports` array, compared to the role of `NgModel`?

Answer (score 2):

Each module can export a set of declarable types - components, directives or pipes. If you want to use any of the declarable type declared in the module other than the one you use declarables from you need to import that module.

`FormsModule` exports the `ngModel` directive that's why you need to import it.

I suggest you read [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)

> Where is this easily documented?

You can go the [documentation of the directive](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) and see which module the it is declared in:

```
Module | import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
```

> What errors should I look out for?

All errors have the same format:

```
Can't bind to <attribute> since it isn't a known property of <element>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to start with going through Angular tutorials or books, read the error text. In your case, it states that ngModel is not a known property of input.  Apparently, you have an HTML input field, which clearly has no ngModel property.

Then google on ngModel Angular and the second link in the search results is this one: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel. It describes what the ngModel is and states that you need to import FormsModel.